# Need a good starting point for twilio on Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, twilio

I've looked at a few approaches to using Twilio with Phonegap and I'm wondering what everyone else would suggest and if anyone's already gone down this path.

I've got a few options, and I'd like to keep it so that I don't have to talk to a backend to send me a token.

1. Old iOS Twilio plugin - This was written for version 2.9 of cordova and looks like it would need some work to be function on 3.0+.
2. JWT - some learning curve here, and I don't know what Twilio would be expecting to see on the opposite side from a token that I create.
3. iOS SDK - totally drop 2 months of work and rewrite everything native.
4. Fail on making it phone only, put up a backend and send everything off to a server to make all the calls and send texts

Has anyone else tried to work with Twilio on Phonegap 3.0+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Friend of Twilio [Jeff Linwood](http://www.jefflinwood.com) has a [Phonegap plugin for Twilio Client](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap).

Not sure if its been updated for the newly release 1.2 version yet, but its a good starting point.

Hope that helps.